# Violation of independence, ANOVA

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, assumptions, biostatistics, independence

I have been asked to analyze data from field observations of a fish community.
Data are collected in two sampling-sites during 16 days (nonconsecutive), twice a day. Dependent variable is biomass.

The aim of the study is to find differences between Day/Night biomass and two tide level biomass, and interaction of those two factors.

If the observations were independent of each other then ANOVA would be OK. But in this case all observations come from only two sites (subjects). Due to fact that there are only two sites, than random effect model or repeated measures ANOVA also can't be used.

What could be solution to use in this situation?

Comment: "*Due to fact that there are only two sites, than random effect model or repeated measures ANOVA also can't be used.*" ... really? Why not? (This is not sarcasm; I may be ignorant of something obvious.)

Comment: At least for random effects models it is advised to have at least 5 levels (Zuur et al. 2009).

Comment: Okay, thanks. But that's not 'can't be used' - rather regarded as 'not advisable'.

Comment: You could use fixed effects instead of random effects. However, it looks like you have dependency not only within sampling-site but also within day (you sampled twice per day and, even though I'm no expert in this field, the measurements are likely to be dependent, aren't they?). Since sampling was done on non-consecutive days, maybe those can be treated as independent, otherwise you have to take into account that too.

Comment: Zuur's recommendations seem different from those of some others; I recall seeing 3 being recommended, but I don't recall where.

Comment: Can't you model the time of day (time1, time2) and sampling site (site1 and site2) as two additional binary factors and model them as fixed effect and check for interactions? (Pardon me if I understood it totally wrong)

Comment: Daytime already is included by factor Day/Night

Comment: Are those two sites really randomly selected? If they're chosen for a reason then I think they would be fixed effects. (If they're just two locations for grabbing fish from the ocean then, yes, they would be random effects.)